# Basis such that projection onto a plane is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Suppose I have been given a vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, and a subspace $W$ (a hyperplane) of it. I wish to find a basis $B$ for $V$ such that we obtain a $B$-diagonal matrix when projecting onto the subspace $W$.

Should we proceed to the above problem by finding the basis of the space $W$ and then somehow extending it to the whole space? May be we should find independent vectors which are orthogonal to vectors in the basis of the hyperplane? Or should we find the projection matrix by using the formula $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ where $A$ consists of columns being the basis of the space $W$ and then appropriately extend it? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to find a basis $B$ for $V$ such that the matrix, corresponding to $B$, of the projection operator onto $W$ is diagonal? That is, you're trying to find a basis that diagonalises projection onto $W$?

Comment: @user837206 yes, that is what I want exactly, so does that mean we need to diagonalize the projection matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Form $B$ by appending a (one-vector) basis for $W^\perp$ to a basis for $W$. Note that $W$ and $W^\perp$ are eigenspaces for the projection operator, corresponding to eigenvalues $1$ and $0$ respectively. Also note their dimensions sum to $\operatorname{dim} V$. Therefore, $B$ is a basis, and indeed a basis of eigenvectors, which diagonalises the projection operator.

Comment: To calculate the orthogonal complement, do we use gram-schmidt?

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, that's one way of doing it: extend the basis of $W$ to a basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$, then apply Gram-Schmidt. This will give you an orthonormal basis that diagonalises the projection operator. Alternatively, if you can find the cartesian form for the hyperplane $W$, you can also just read off the coefficients to find a normal vector which will span $W^\perp$.